# How can i import a Eclipse launch-group configuration into another workspace along with project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, launching-application

I have created a launch group configuration for launching a project in my current workspace. 
Can i some how save the configuration along with the project so that it can be imported into another workspace ?
If no how can i create a launch-group configuration using a custom eclipse plugin ?

Comment: You can but I can't remember the steps so I'm not going to make this an answer.  You have to open the launch (Run...) configurations and choose to export.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Export

`File -> Export... -> Run/Debug -> "Launch Configurations"`

Then select the configurations you need to export.

### Import

`File -> Import... -> Run/Debug -> "Launch Configurations"`

Then select the configurations into "From Directory".

Example [images are available here](http://www.digizol.com/2013/11/eclipse-export-import-launch-configurations.html) along with a sample .launch file.

Answer (score 0):

I simply export all my `"run/debug configurations"` from the original project by:

**copying the content of folder**:

```
$My-Workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.debug.core\.launches
```

**into a folder in the destination project** (*folder location or name doesn't matter, just as long as it is in the imported project*)

and when I open eclipse to my workspace and the project - it will show up automatically in `"run/debug configurations"` dialog (eclipse scan the projects for **.launch** files)

also after copying a **.launch** file into my project, i right click the root folder and choose refresh, wait for a minute and the configurations appear in the `"run/debug configurations"`